# i have three tables with name emp, section,Type now i need the combination of statements

Tags: sql

i have two tables with name emp, dept, now i need the combination of statements means

**columns of emp table**

`empid | deptid | fulltime | parttime | contracttime`

**dept table**

`section id | dept id` and some other columns which are not that much needed.

Now in emp table :

```
empid | dept id | fulltime | parttime | contrattime 
----------------------------------------------------
    1 |   1     |  0       | 0        |   1    
    2 |   1     |  1       | 1        |   0
```

and so on are there, and
in dept table there are 7 row like 
section id and dept id as follows

```
    1  1
    2  1
    3  1
    4  1
    5  1
    6  1
    7  1
```

these now i want if the columns 
fulltime part time contract time

```
 if 0 0 1 then it should go to section id 1
 if 1 1 0 then section id 2
 if 1 1 1 then section id 3
 if 1 0 1 then section id 4 
 if 0 1 1 then section id 5
 if 1 0 0 then section id 6
 if 0 1 0 then section id 7
```

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: the IF statement in queries is [CASE](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlcase.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE statement in join like this:

```
select *
      from emp e
        join dept d 
          on d.deptid = e.deptid
            and (case
                   when e.fulltime = 0 and e.parttime = 0 and e.contracttime = 1 then 1
                   when e.fulltime = 1 and e.parttime = 1 and e.contracttime = 0 then 2
                   when e.fulltime = 1 and e.parttime = 1 and e.contracttime = 1 then 3
                   when e.fulltime = 1 and e.parttime = 0 and e.contracttime = 1 then 4
                   when e.fulltime = 0 and e.parttime = 1 and e.contracttime = 1 then 5
                   when e.fulltime = 1 and e.parttime = 0 and e.contracttime = 0 then 6
                   when e.fulltime = 0 and e.parttime = 1 and e.contracttime = 0 then 7
                   else 0
                 end) = d.sectionid;
```

Only problem here might be the performance as indexes will not be used unless you create some complicate dfunctional index.